# Programmatically query a database table via active record in a rake task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am making a rake task:

```
task :populate => :environment do
    table_array = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables #=> ["types","products"]

    table_array.each do |t|
        puts t

        instance_string = t.capitalize.singularize.to_s #=> "Type" (on the first loop)
        puts Type.column_names #=> ["id", "type_name", "created_at", "updated_at"]

        # This will return an error, undefined method 'column_names'
        puts "#{instance_string}".column_names
    end
end
```

Now, despite having an instance string of "Type" (on the first loop), I can't use it to programtically query the database. Constants can't be evaluated in the same way that instance variables and local variables can, it seems. How can I Programmatically an array of column names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `t.classify.constantize` it returns `Type` as a class on which you can call the method `column_names` or any other class method.

Read more about [classify](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/Inflector/classify) and [constantize](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/Inflector/constantize)

Comment: hmm..it's sort of working, but I'm getting **uninitialized constant Type** error, which I think means the constant isn't getting its attributes from its database table? It's a rake task I'm working on, but Active Record is working, so why would this happen?

Comment: **uninitialized constant Type** means that the `Type` clas has not been defined within that scope, does `Type.column_names` work in the same scope?

Comment: Yes, not sure what I was doing wrong. All working now, thanks!